# SQL Nested Query based on value of Dependent Column

Tags: sql, join, case, decode

In the below table structure, TB_Vehicles is the Master table and TB_Cars, TB_Bikes, TB_Cars are Satellite tables which hold more info about respective vehicles.

```
**TB_Scooters**                 
V_NAME  V_ID    V_YEAR  V_TYPE  V_MILEAGE   
Activa  10  2003    Scooter 45  
Access  20  2004    Scooter 50  

**TB_Bikes**                    
V_NAME  V_ID    V_YEAR  V_TYPE  V_ENGINE    
Karizma 30  2001    Bike    180 
Pulsar  40  2008    Bike    150 

**TB_Cars**                 
V_NAME  V_ID    V_YEAR  V_TYPE  V_CAR_TYPE  
Linea   50  2011    Car Sedan   
i20 60  2012    Car Sedan   

**TB_Vehicles**                 
V_NAME  V_ID    V_YEAR  V_TYPE  V_COLOR V_AVAILABLE
Activa  10  2003    Scooter Black   Yes
Access  20  2004    Scooter Black   No
Karizma 30  2001    Bike    Red Yes
Pulsar  40  2008    Bike    Black   Yes
Linea   50  2011    Car White   No
i20 60  2012    Car Red Yes
```

I want users to search using the Name. So, when users enter Name as 'Access', my query should give all information about that vehicle, including that from Satellite Tables (using both TB_Vehicles and TB_Scooters).

```
SELECT * FROM TB_Vehicles
WHERE V_NAME = 'Access';
```

Similarly, if user enters 'Linea', it should give info from TB_Vehicles and TB_Cars tables.

So, with V_NAME as input, I'll find V_TYPE from TB_Vehicles table, and using that, I need to identify which satellite table, I need to join to retrieve more info.

How do I do this? Can you please help me with the query? Do I need to use CASE or DECODE to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

The requirement here is to display only those columns which are applicable for that particular vehicle type. So, when user gives 'Access' as input, it should display all columns from TB_Vehicles table, and V_MILEAGE from TB_Scooters table.

I was thinking whether this can be done using CASE or DECODE, where I first identify the type (V_TYPE) of the vehicle from TB_Vehicles table using the input name (V_NAME), and then based on this V_TYPE, I'll search the relevant table and display only relevant columns.

When Input Name is 'Access', then result should be:

```
V_NAME     V_ID   V_YEAR   V_TYPE    V_COLOR   V_AVAILABLE   V_MILEAGE  
Access   20     2004     Scooter   Black     No            50
```

When Input Name is 'i20', then result should be:

```
V_NAME     V_ID   V_YEAR   V_TYPE   V_COLOR   V_AVAILABLE   V_CAR_TYPE  
i20      60     2012     Car      Red       Yes           Sedan
```

Comment: .. You cannot do what you want using basic SQL.  A `select` statement defines the columns that are being returned; these cannot change names or types depending on parameters to the query.  Your best bet is to return all the columns, populating the unused ones with `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be storing the name in both the vehicles tables and the subtables.  If this is common information, then just store it in the vehicles table.  This is true of all the common columns.

Next, when you access data, do it by bringing together all the tables:

```
select v.*,
       s.v_mileage, b.v_engine, c.v_car_type
from TB_vehicles v left join
     TB_Scooters s
     on s.v_id = v.v_id and v.type = 'scooter' left join
     TB_Bikes b
     on b.v_id = v.v_id and v.type = 'bike' left join
     TB_Cars c
     on c.v_id = v.vid and v.type = 'car';
```

From this query, you can then choose the row and the fields that you want.

However, you need to work on normalizing your data structure so fields like `v_year` are only in one table.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon As per your suggestions, I tried the following query: 

SELECT v.*, s.v_mileage, b.v_engine, c.v_car_type
FROM tb_vehicles v 
  LEFT JOIN tb_scooters s
    ON s.v_id = v.v_id
    AND v.v_type = 'Scooter'
  LEFT JOIN tb_bikes b
    ON b.v_id = v.v_id
    AND v.v_type = 'Bike'
  LEFT JOIN tb_cars c
    ON c.v_id = v.v_id
    AND v.v_type = 'Car'
WHERE v.v_name = 'Access';

Comment: But, here, the requirement is to display only those columns which are applicable for that particular vehicle type. So, when I have given 'Access' as input, it shoudl display all columns from TB_Vehicles, and v_mileage from TB_Scooters.

Also, I don't have an option to create any temporary table or view for this. I was thinking whether this can be done using CASE or DECODE, where I first identify the type of the vehicle from TB_Vehicles table using V_NAME, and then based on this V_TYPE, I'll search the relevant table and display the other columns.

Please advise.

Comment: @NiCKz . . . You cannot, using regular SQL, change the structure of the result set.  The number and names of the columns are fixed by the `SELECT` statement.  You can assign `NULL` values to unused fields.  Or use generic names.  You should modify your question with an example of the output you want.

Comment: I have modified my question. I'm not sure if I am able to put forth the requirements clearly. Please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon! Appreciate your help over this...
For others with similar query, please look into the above response from Gordon as well as the below link:
http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/189451/180198/